# DokuWiki and SQL code

Tags: sql, dokuwiki

I recently installed DokuWiki on my domain and ran in one nasty problem.
I am trying to enter such code:

```
CREATE TABLE LOOM(
    ID      INT NOT NULL,
    KIIP_ID INT NOT NULL,
    NIMI    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    SYND    DATE NOT NULL,
    SURM    DATE,        
    PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

between   tags and if I am trying to preview or save the change, DokuWiki shows me this:

```
This topic does not exist yet
You've followed a link to a topic that doesn't exist yet. If permissions allow, you may create it by using the Create this page button.
```

How to fix this?

Comment: I am using DokuWiki Release 2011-05-25 "Rincewind". Very important part, the part what really causes the problem is "CREATE TABLE" and it takes me to error 403 actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.dokuwiki.org/faq:mod_security

Comment: @andreas-gohr Thank You! I guess I need to contact my support, because adding those rules gives me error 500.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the commands between the `<code></code>` tags. Like the below.

`<code>
CREATE TABLE LOOM(
    ID      INT NOT NULL,
    KIIP_ID INT NOT NULL,
    NIMI    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    SYND    DATE NOT NULL,
    SURM    DATE,

    PRIMARY KEY (ID));
</code>`

If you still have problems previewing then Andreas is right it is most likely a web server configuration issue with Apache. To validate that you could redploy on nginx and see if the issue still persists. I have a tutorial about deploying dokuwiki on nginx here: http://bigthinkingapplied.com/launching-a-private-wikipedia-using-dokuwiki/